# Is it possible to calculate the color balance of an SVG image using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, effects, svg-filters

Is there any way to calculate the color-balance of an SVG image using Javascript?

(I can find the color-balance of a Canvas image using a library like pixastic but I need it in SVG)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, unfortunately there is no facility in SVG to enable this directly.

Comment: thanks,

is there any limitation in quality of svg filters? because if I apply an svg filter like brightness or greyscale on my dark image I see a very bad quality?

Comment: "quality' can mean many different things. If you mean you're getting pixelation, then you can force a higher quality through the use of the filterRes property. If you're talking about banding or other artifacts - Firefox on Windows is particularly susceptible to these problems, but all the other browsers seem to do a pretty good job.

Comment: yes I mean getting pixelation , when I apply for example a grayscale filter using SVG and I put the attribute filterRes to a hight value, I get usually a bad quality of my image mainly when I used a dark image

Comment: I add an image with filter svg grayscale